# Printing char[] core dump C

Tags: c, char, printf, coredump

I'm Trying to do:

```
printf("Provider: %s\n", Props->providerName);
```

where struct member (from external library) is:

```
char providerName[256];
```

causes core dump with gdb output of:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 73950    ]
#0  0xfee22290 in strlen () from /lib/libc.so.1
```

I guess the char[] might not be null terminated, but what is the best solution?

Cheers!

---

edit: The structure I'm using is from an external library, and appears not to be null (I can successfully print another of its members `char alias[256];`

Comment: How do you fill `providerName` with data?

Comment: What did you do to make it non-null-terminated?

Comment: The best solution is to null terminate `providerName` in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure `Props` is non-NULL and valid?

Comment: So solving one segfault led to another. This is a classic case for gdb and valgrind. Trust me, you'll solve your problem faster that way, or at least be able to share with SO the *real* problem. It's very hard to debug over the intertubez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a maximum-width indicator whenever you can when using `%s` with printf:

```
printf("Provider: %.255s\n", Props->providerName);
```

If you still get a segfault, and Props is not `NULL`, you probably have a clash between your headers and the library binaries. Suppose you have the new version of headers that define:

```
struct Thing {
    int foo[256];
    int bar[256];
    int baz[256];
};
```

but the library binaries are outdated, using the following definition:

```
struct Thing {
    int foo[256];
    int bar[256];
};
```

If you now try to access `baz` you'll get a segmentation fault, even though the other members work fine.

*(edit: added text from "if you get a segfault" to end of answer)*

Comment: What if the actual data is only 10 characters? While it won't seg fault (here but in some other string function that may require it to be null terminated it will so I think this is just hiding a bug), 245 characters of garbage will be printed.

Comment: I tried this and get a different error: `Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 74518    ]
#0  0xfee2193c in memchr () from /lib/libc.so.1`

Comment: @Ant Then `Props` is probably `NULL` or stale. Try running your program with a debugger.

Comment: @AntWilson - You really should use 'valgrind' and 'gdb'. You will solve your memory problems faster. You can always come back to SO once you've got a concrete problem that we can see.

Comment: the error posted was obtained using gdb. And props isn't null because I can successfully print another of its members `char     alias[256];`

Comment: @hmjd I always limit the length of data everywhere to avoid forgetting buffer-overrun safeguards (esp. in sprintf), but you're right, it needs to be null-terminated too.

Comment: `sprintf()` yes, but here I don't think it helps to fix the program. It may prevent a seg fault, but the program remains incorrect.

Comment: @AntWilson Are you sure your definition of the `struct` is identical to the library's? And your header file version agrees with the binary version of the lib?

Comment: @IlmoEuro I think you might be right, I've found conflicting types for `providerName` in separate OS documentation, I will investigate further

Answer (score 1):

*Update:*  Improved `printf()` to `putchar()`.

Some other, good answers have been given.  In case one does not wish to alter providerName, however, a loop with `break` is called for:

```
int i;
printf("Provider: ");
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    const char c = Props->providerName[i];
    if (!c) break;
    putchar(c);
}
putchar('\n');
```

Naturally, one must earlier have set `const int N = 256` or `#define N 256` or the like.  One can encapsulate the loop in a function call or macro if desired.

Incidentally, the loop above does nothing `printf()` would not have had to do, anyway; so it runs fast, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

`Props->providerName[255] = 0;` prior to using it will ensure your data is NULL terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Use strcpy(Props->providerName, "IBM") if you want Enter "IBM" as provider name.
or use gets(str)  for take input in str and then use.
Also best way to compile your program with gdb and print the value using p Props to check the valuse which Props is pointing

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be matter of the kind of data contained in `providerName`.

Most likely `Props` does reference an invalid memory location, `NULL` for example.

You could test this using a debug modification like so:

```
char * p = Props->providerName;
printf("Provider: %s\n", p);
```

I bet it crashes when trying to execute the first line.

An alternative way to implement this more flexible could be:

```
printf("Provider: %*s%s\n", 
  sizeof (Props->providerName), 
  Props ?Props->providerName :"<no properties available>", 
  Props ?(Props->providerName[sizeof(Props->Props->providerName) - 1] ?" <cut off>" :"") :"");
```

Comment: If resorting to printf for debugging, why not just `printf("Props is at 0x%p\n", Props);`?

Comment: sure ... - one could also do `gdb <executable> <core>` and then issue a `p Props`. ;-)

Comment: of course, but you didn't suggest using gdb in your post, you suggested adding a printf.